# jQuery case AND

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem and I dont know what to search to find my solution.

I want the case to only give me a success message when "myString" equals a certain value and when it doesnt, it gives a error message

```
case "test" + myString:
$("#placeholder").prepend("Cant test ",myString ,"<br>");
break;

case "test" + (myString == " this"):
$("#placeholder").prepend("Tested ",myString ,"<br>");
break;
```

Comment: Please post the complete switch statement and perhaps some HTML. Not sure what you expect the second case to be. "test"+1 if true

Comment: what you want exactly?

Comment: Why don't you go with the __if-else__ statement?

Comment: why not just `case "test this"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make that using a condition inside a case:

```
case 'test' + myString:
    if (myString == ' this') {
        $("#placeholder").prepend("Tested ",myString ,"<br>");
    }
    break;
```